# Android App Force Closing

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, force-close, java

```
01-02 15:30:21.361: E/AndroidRuntime(3764): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-02 15:30:21.361: E/AndroidRuntime(3764): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-02 15:30:21.361: E/AndroidRuntime(3764):     at com.htc.music.browserlayer.fragment.HtcMusicFragment.initLyricsView(HtcMusicFragment.java:8905)
01-02 15:30:21.361: E/AndroidRuntime(3764):     at com.htc.music.browserlayer.fragment.HtcMusicFragment.initialUI(HtcMusicFragment.java:2305)
01-02 15:30:21.361: E/AndroidRuntime(3764):     at com.htc.music.browserlayer.fragment.HtcMusicFragment.onCreateView(HtcMusicFragment.java:662)
01-02 15:30:21.361: E/AndroidRuntime(3764):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java)
01-02 15:30:21.361: E/AndroidRuntime(3764):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java)
01-02 15:30:21.361: E/AndroidRuntime(3764):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java)
01-02 15:30:21.361: E/AndroidRuntime(3764):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java)
01-02 15:30:21.361: E/AndroidRuntime(3764):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java)
01-02 15:30:21.361: E/AndroidRuntime(3764):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java)
01-02 15:30:21.361: E/AndroidRuntime(3764):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
01-02 15:30:21.361: E/AndroidRuntime(3764):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
01-02 15:30:21.361: E/AndroidRuntime(3764):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
01-02 15:30:21.361: E/AndroidRuntime(3764):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-02 15:30:21.361: E/AndroidRuntime(3764):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
01-02 15:30:21.361: E/AndroidRuntime(3764):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
01-02 15:30:21.361: E/AndroidRuntime(3764):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
01-02 15:30:21.361: E/AndroidRuntime(3764):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-02 15:30:21.541: E/EmbeddedLogger(2496): App crashed! Process: com.htc.music
01-02 15:30:21.541: E/EmbeddedLogger(2496): App crashed! Package: com.htc.music v522301810 (5.1.2320352112.658919.648253)
01-02 15:30:22.081: E/EmbeddedLogger(2496): Application Label: Music
```

I open Music app in Android but it force close. I have taken logcat and found this problem causing.

At Line 8905 here is the code :

```
> if-eqz v11, :cond_1
> 
> const-string v11, "[HtcMusicFragment]"
> 
> const-string v12, "onServiceConnectedHandle, mActivity is null
```

Comment: That looks like a bug in the app. You should contact the app developer and let them know about it. If _you're_ the app developer, then you're on the wrong site. Please read the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

## Conclusion

This is a programming error within the HTC Music app (based on the package id). The best option is to report this error to the developers using the force close dialog.

## More details

As a programmer I recognize the nullpointer exception thrown in the `HtcMusicFragment` at line 8905. The package (and class name) indicate that this is an app from HTC for Music playing.

Since this code is closed there is no reason to look further into this yourself, even if you had the knowledge. Let's say it would be perfectly possible to decompile the app (it isn't) and fix the nullpointer even then you wouldn't be able to replace the app on your phone since this is a vendor app. That is without root.

If you want to read about the nullpointer exception try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception In short there is a method called on an object that hasn't been initialized properly. It's up to the programmer to check for these kind of issues.

## My advice

Go get a better music app on the google play store.